# Amazon athena don't use glue catalog

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have created a database with a table using aws glue crawler. In athena, I cant choose that database/table for query. I think problem can be in service region location. My setup is next :

1. s3 csv file is located in Ireland
2. aws glue crawler was created without any option that points to its location, but its accessible via next url - https://console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home?region=*us-east-1* . So I think it's created in us-east-1 region, but I am not sure. Region parameter appears on any page of my account.

Also see attachments

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you check here: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-upgrade.html?

Looks like you need to perform some AWS Glue upgrade, and also add policies so that Athena can pull catalog information.  Also, FAQ is available here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-faq.html.  I have not worked on this scenario yet, but working on Glue - Redshift.

In the FAQ, its mentioned as follows:

> Why do I need to add AWS Glue policies to Athena users?
>   Before you upgrade, Athena manages the data catalog, so Athena actions must be
>   allowed for your users to perform queries. After you upgrade to the
>   AWS Glue Data Catalog, Athena actions no longer apply to accessing the
>   AWS Glue Data Catalog, so AWS Glue actions must be allowed for your
>   users. Remember, the managed policy for Athena has already been
>   updated to allow the required AWS Glue actions, so no action is
>   required if you use the managed policy.
>
> What happens if I don’t allow AWS Glue policies for Athena users?
>
> If you upgrade to the AWS Glue Data Catalog and don't update a user's
>   customer-managed or inline IAM policies, Athena queries fail because
>   the user won't be allowed to perform actions in AWS Glue. For the
>   specific actions to allow, see Step 2 - Update Customer-Managed/Inline
>   Policies Associated with Athena Users.

Comment: according to first link - After you upgrade, the Athena console has a link to open the AWS Glue Catalog Manager from within Athena - I have that.

Comment: I have updated my answer with FAQ section about applying custom or inline policies.  May be you need to add these policies.  I have checked in my Athena console and am able to view the db/tables that were created using AWS Glue crawlers.